# About spectrum, point spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

X is a Banach space and $T \in K(X)/\{0\}$ and following is given
(Definitions of point spectrum etc. together with $\{0\}=\sigma(T)$)
\begin{align}
\{0\}=\sigma(T):=& \mathbb{K}/\{\lambda\in \mathbb{K}|ker(\lambda*Id-T)=\{0\}\cap Im(\lambda*Id-T)=X\}\\
\sigma_p(T):=&\{\lambda\in\sigma(T)|ker(\lambda*Id-T)\neq\{0\}\}\\
\sigma_c(T):=& \mathbb{K}/\{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}|ker(\lambda*Id-T)=\{0\}\cap Im(\lambda*Id-T)\neq X \cap \overline{Im(\lambda*Id-T)} = X\}\\
\sigma_r(T):=& \mathbb{K}/\{\lambda\in \mathbb{R}|ker(\lambda*Id-T)=\{0\}\cap \overline{Im(\lambda*Id-T)}\neq X\}
\end{align}

The task now is to find out if there are Banach spaces X and Operators $T \in K(X)/\{0\}$ with

$$ i) \sigma_p(T)= \{0\}  $$
$$ii) \sigma_c(T)= \{0\}  $$
$$iii) \sigma_r(T)= \{0\}  $$

For i) I guess its wrong because $ker(-T) =\{0\}$

I dont know about the other cases though.

Comment: It looks like cases (i)-(iii) are the same!

Comment: Thanks for correction. Its the other spectra of course.